# How to convert from jpg to bmp by using CImg library?

Tags: c++, cimg

I want to convert JPG to BMP file. I am using a library called `CImg`.
I am using the following code to do the conversion operation:

```
#include "CImg.h"  
using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    CImg<unsigned char> image("picture.jpg");
    image.save_bmp("imgB.bmp");

    return 0;
}
```

But the following error occurs:

[image]

What might be the problem. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Is your image really JPG or a PNG or something with extension .jpg? try another image.

Comment: @Avezan: Yes JPG. I have tried another 2 JPG files and the problem still appears

Comment: have you tried it with complete path, they sometimes are mess on windows.

Comment: @Avezan: Yes with the complete path the problem still appears.

Comment: Have you installed GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick. The first message is that gm.exe cannot be found. gm means GraphicsMagick. CIMG, I believe needs one or the other to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem happens because you have not installed **ImageMagick**.

> Note that you must also have installed the **ImageMagick** package in order to be able to read JPG images.

If you are going to install **ImageMagick** into not standard path, then you will need to specify it's path like below

```
cimg::imagemagick_path("C:\\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16\\convert.exe");
```

If you don't want to install **ImageMagick** then you should link your code with **libjpeg** library and enable native JPG file support in CImg, putting this before including CImg.h:

```
#define cimg_use_jpeg
#include "CImg.h"
```

Using CImg with **libjpeg** is definitely better. That works the same for other image formats (tiff, png, ...).

Comment: Hey @S.M, how do I link my code with the [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) library?